# Create XSL file from XML

Tags: xml, xslt, xsl-fo

I have XML file with multiple invoice in the same file but not sure how I can create XSL file to separate all the invoices from one XML file. Is there any quick way or tool to do this. Please advise and thank you in advance.

Please see it says Customer Invoice Count = 15, so this has total of 15 invoices but I delete some from the bottom since the file was too large to display here.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<EDI_DOCUMENT version="1.0">
  <EDI_CUSTOMER>SOT000</EDI_CUSTOMER>
  <CUSTOMER INVOICE_COUNT="15">
    <CUST_ID>0546981413</CUST_ID>
    <CUST_NAME>COMPANY NAME</CUST_NAME>
    <PHONE>714/222-5525</PHONE>
    <CONTACT_NAME>CASEY DAVIS</CONTACT_NAME>
    <ADDRESS1>1252 Rose St</ADDRESS1>
    <CITY>Costa Mesa</CITY>
    <STATE>CA</STATE>
    <POSTAL>92626-4300</POSTAL>
    <COLLECTOR>Jackson, Thembi</COLLECTOR>
    <CLCT_PHONE>x1077</CLCT_PHONE>
    <CLCT_EMAIL>nelli.jackson@office.com</CLCT_EMAIL>
    <INVOICE DETAIL_COUNT="21">
      <INV_AR_ID>005700658035A</INV_AR_ID>
      <SOLDTO_ID>0345961518</SOLDTO_ID>
      <SOLDTO_NAME>COMPANY NAME</SOLDTO_NAME>
      <CARD_NO>0000</CARD_NO>
      <CARD_NAME>COMPANY NAME</CARD_NAME>
      <CARD_PHONE>714/222-5525</CARD_PHONE>
      <SIGNEE_NAME>elizabeth moore</SIGNEE_NAME>
      <SIGNEE_PHONE>9495016213</SIGNEE_PHONE>
      <INV_TRANS_ID>10647551</INV_TRANS_ID>
      <INV_TYPE>IN</INV_TYPE>
      <INV_DATE>01/06/16</INV_DATE>
      <INV_AMOUNT>49.90</INV_AMOUNT>
      <INV_CUR_CD>USD</INV_CUR_CD>
      <INV_TAX_TOTAL>3.70</INV_TAX_TOTAL>
      <INV_DISC_TOTAL>0.00</INV_DISC_TOTAL>
      <LINE_DISC_TOTAL>-141.83</LINE_DISC_TOTAL>
      <STORE>0303</STORE>
      <STORE_NAME>Costa Mesa CA</STORE_NAME>
      <STORE_ADDR>1234 Newport Blvd Ste E101</STORE_ADDR>
      <STORE_CITY>Costa Mesa</STORE_CITY>
      <STORE_STATE>CA</STORE_STATE>
      <STORE_POSTAL>92627</STORE_POSTAL>
      <STORE_CNTRY>USA</STORE_CNTRY>
      <PO_REF>0162011156-5711MV US DBQs</PO_REF>
      <DETAIL>
        <ITEM>0001</ITEM>
        <ITEM_DESCR>FS B&amp;W S/S White Standard</ITEM_DESCR>
        <UNIT_OF_MEASURE>EA</UNIT_OF_MEASURE>
        <LIST_PRICE>0.12000</LIST_PRICE>
        <QTY>15</QTY>
        <UNIT_PRICE>0.03200</UNIT_PRICE>
        <LINE_DISC_UNIT>-0.08800</LINE_DISC_UNIT>
        <INV_DISC_UNIT>0.00000</INV_DISC_UNIT>
        <GROSS_EXT_AMT>1.80</GROSS_EXT_AMT>
        <LINE_DISC_AMT>-1.32</LINE_DISC_AMT>
        <INV_DISC_AMT>0.00</INV_DISC_AMT>
        <ITEM_TAX>0.00</ITEM_TAX>
        <EXTENDED_AMT>0.48</EXTENDED_AMT>
      </DETAIL>
      <DETAIL>
        <ITEM>0001</ITEM>
        <ITEM_DESCR>FS B&amp;W S/S White Standard</ITEM_DESCR>
        <UNIT_OF_MEASURE>EA</UNIT_OF_MEASURE>
        <LIST_PRICE>0.12000</LIST_PRICE>
        <QTY>15</QTY>
        <UNIT_PRICE>0.03200</UNIT_PRICE>
        <LINE_DISC_UNIT>-0.08800</LINE_DISC_UNIT>
        <INV_DISC_UNIT>0.00000</INV_DISC_UNIT>
        <GROSS_EXT_AMT>1.80</GROSS_EXT_AMT>
        <LINE_DISC_AMT>-1.32</LINE_DISC_AMT>
        <INV_DISC_AMT>0.00</INV_DISC_AMT>
        <ITEM_TAX>0.00</ITEM_TAX>
        <EXTENDED_AMT>0.48</EXTENDED_AMT>
      </DETAIL>
      <DETAIL>
        <ITEM>0001</ITEM>
        <ITEM_DESCR>FS B&amp;W S/S White Standard</ITEM_DESCR>
        <UNIT_OF_MEASURE>EA</UNIT_OF_MEASURE>
        <LIST_PRICE>0.12000</LIST_PRICE>
        <QTY>15</QTY>
        <UNIT_PRICE>0.03200</UNIT_PRICE>
        <LINE_DISC_UNIT>-0.08800</LINE_DISC_UNIT>
        <INV_DISC_UNIT>0.00000</INV_DISC_UNIT>
        <GROSS_EXT_AMT>1.80</GROSS_EXT_AMT>
        <LINE_DISC_AMT>-1.32</LINE_DISC_AMT>
        <INV_DISC_AMT>0.00</INV_DISC_AMT>
        <ITEM_TAX>0.00</ITEM_TAX>
        <EXTENDED_AMT>0.48</EXTENDED_AMT>
      </DETAIL>
      <DETAIL>
        <ITEM>0001</ITEM>
        <ITEM_DESCR>FS B&amp;W S/S White Standard</ITEM_DESCR>
        <UNIT_OF_MEASURE>EA</UNIT_OF_MEASURE>
        <LIST_PRICE>0.12000</LIST_PRICE>
        <QTY>15</QTY>
        <UNIT_PRICE>0.03200</UNIT_PRICE>
        <LINE_DISC_UNIT>-0.08800</LINE_DISC_UNIT>
        <INV_DISC_UNIT>0.00000</INV_DISC_UNIT>
        <GROSS_EXT_AMT>1.80</GROSS_EXT_AMT>
        <LINE_DISC_AMT>-1.32</LINE_DISC_AMT>
        <INV_DISC_AMT>0.00</INV_DISC_AMT>
        <ITEM_TAX>0.00</ITEM_TAX>
        <EXTENDED_AMT>0.48</EXTENDED_AMT>
      </DETAIL>
      <DETAIL>
        <ITEM>0033</ITEM>
        <ITEM_DESCR>FS B&amp;W D/S 8.5x11 D/S Standard</ITEM_DESCR>
        <UNIT_OF_MEASURE>EA</UNIT_OF_MEASURE>
        <LIST_PRICE>0.24000</LIST_PRICE>
        <QTY>90</QTY>
        <UNIT_PRICE>0.06400</UNIT_PRICE>
        <LINE_DISC_UNIT>-0.17600</LINE_DISC_UNIT>
        <INV_DISC_UNIT>0.00000</INV_DISC_UNIT>
        <GROSS_EXT_AMT>21.60</GROSS_EXT_AMT>
        <LINE_DISC_AMT>-15.84</LINE_DISC_AMT>
        <INV_DISC_AMT>0.00</INV_DISC_AMT>
        <ITEM_TAX>0.00</ITEM_TAX>
        <EXTENDED_AMT>5.76</EXTENDED_AMT>
      </DETAIL>
      <DETAIL>
        <ITEM>0033</ITEM>
        <ITEM_DESCR>FS B&amp;W D/S 8.5x11 D/S Standard</ITEM_DESCR>
        <UNIT_OF_MEASURE>EA</UNIT_OF_MEASURE>
        <LIST_PRICE>0.24000</LIST_PRICE>
        <QTY>90</QTY>
        <UNIT_PRICE>0.06400</UNIT_PRICE>
        <LINE_DISC_UNIT>-0.17600</LINE_DISC_UNIT>
        <INV_DISC_UNIT>0.00000</INV_DISC_UNIT>
        <GROSS_EXT_AMT>21.60</GROSS_EXT_AMT>
        <LINE_DISC_AMT>-15.84</LINE_DISC_AMT>
        <INV_DISC_AMT>0.00</INV_DISC_AMT>
        <ITEM_TAX>0.00</ITEM_TAX>
        <EXTENDED_AMT>5.76</EXTENDED_AMT>
      </DETAIL>
      <DETAIL>
        <ITEM>0033</ITEM>
        <ITEM_DESCR>FS B&amp;W D/S 8.5x11 D/S Standard</ITEM_DESCR>
        <UNIT_OF_MEASURE>EA</UNIT_OF_MEASURE>
        <LIST_PRICE>0.24000</LIST_PRICE>
        <QTY>90</QTY>
        <UNIT_PRICE>0.06400</UNIT_PRICE>
        <LINE_DISC_UNIT>-0.17600</LINE_DISC_UNIT>
        <INV_DISC_UNIT>0.00000</INV_DISC_UNIT>
        <GROSS_EXT_AMT>21.60</GROSS_EXT_AMT>
        <LINE_DISC_AMT>-15.84</LINE_DISC_AMT>
        <INV_DISC_AMT>0.00</INV_DISC_AMT>
        <ITEM_TAX>0.00</ITEM_TAX>
        <EXTENDED_AMT>5.76</EXTENDED_AMT>
      </DETAIL>
      <DETAIL>
        <ITEM>0033</ITEM>
        <ITEM_DESCR>FS B&amp;W D/S 8.5x11 D/S Standard</ITEM_DESCR>
        <UNIT_OF_MEASURE>EA</UNIT_OF_MEASURE>
        <LIST_PRICE>0.24000</LIST_PRICE>
        <QTY>75</QTY>
        <UNIT_PRICE>0.06400</UNIT_PRICE>
        <LINE_DISC_UNIT>-0.17600</LINE_DISC_UNIT>
        <INV_DISC_UNIT>0.00000</INV_DISC_UNIT>
        <GROSS_EXT_AMT>18.00</GROSS_EXT_AMT>
        <LINE_DISC_AMT>-13.20</LINE_DISC_AMT>
        <INV_DISC_AMT>0.00</INV_DISC_AMT>
        <ITEM_TAX>0.00</ITEM_TAX>
        <EXTENDED_AMT>4.80</EXTENDED_AMT>
      </DETAIL>
      <DETAIL>
        <ITEM>0033</ITEM>
        <ITEM_DESCR>FS B&amp;W D/S 8.5x11 D/S Standard</ITEM_DESCR>
        <UNIT_OF_MEASURE>EA</UNIT_OF_MEASURE>
        <LIST_PRICE>0.24000</LIST_PRICE>
        <QTY>75</QTY>
        <UNIT_PRICE>0.06400</UNIT_PRICE>
        <LINE_DISC_UNIT>-0.17600</LINE_DISC_UNIT>
        <INV_DISC_UNIT>0.00000</INV_DISC_UNIT>
        <GROSS_EXT_AMT>18.00</GROSS_EXT_AMT>
        <LINE_DISC_AMT>-13.20</LINE_DISC_AMT>
        <INV_DISC_AMT>0.00</INV_DISC_AMT>
        <ITEM_TAX>0.00</ITEM_TAX>
        <EXTENDED_AMT>4.80</EXTENDED_AMT>
      </DETAIL>
      <DETAIL>
        <ITEM>0033</ITEM>
        <ITEM_DESCR>FS B&amp;W D/S 8.5x11 D/S Standard</ITEM_DESCR>
        <UNIT_OF_MEASURE>EA</UNIT_OF_MEASURE>
        <LIST_PRICE>0.24000</LIST_PRICE>
        <QTY>90</QTY>
        <UNIT_PRICE>0.06400</UNIT_PRICE>
        <LINE_DISC_UNIT>-0.17600</LINE_DISC_UNIT>
        <INV_DISC_UNIT>0.00000</INV_DISC_UNIT>
        <GROSS_EXT_AMT>21.60</GROSS_EXT_AMT>
        <LINE_DISC_AMT>-15.84</LINE_DISC_AMT>
        <INV_DISC_AMT>0.00</INV_DISC_AMT>
        <ITEM_TAX>0.00</ITEM_TAX>
        <EXTENDED_AMT>5.76</EXTENDED_AMT>
      </DETAIL>
      <DETAIL>
        <ITEM>0033</ITEM>
        <ITEM_DESCR>FS B&amp;W D/S 8.5x11 D/S Standard</ITEM_DESCR>
        <UNIT_OF_MEASURE>EA</UNIT_OF_MEASURE>
        <LIST_PRICE>0.24000</LIST_PRICE>
        <QTY>75</QTY>
        <UNIT_PRICE>0.06400</UNIT_PRICE>
        <LINE_DISC_UNIT>-0.17600</LINE_DISC_UNIT>
        <INV_DISC_UNIT>0.00000</INV_DISC_UNIT>
        <GROSS_EXT_AMT>18.00</GROSS_EXT_AMT>
        <LINE_DISC_AMT>-13.20</LINE_DISC_AMT>
        <INV_DISC_AMT>0.00</INV_DISC_AMT>
        <ITEM_TAX>0.00</ITEM_TAX>
        <EXTENDED_AMT>4.80</EXTENDED_AMT>
      </DETAIL>
      <DETAIL>
        <ITEM>0033</ITEM>
        <ITEM_DESCR>FS B&amp;W D/S 8.5x11 D/S Standard</ITEM_DESCR>
        <UNIT_OF_MEASURE>EA</UNIT_OF_MEASURE>
        <LIST_PRICE>0.24000</LIST_PRICE>
        <QTY>75</QTY>
        <UNIT_PRICE>0.06400</UNIT_PRICE>
        <LINE_DISC_UNIT>-0.17600</LINE_DISC_UNIT>
        <INV_DISC_UNIT>0.00000</INV_DISC_UNIT>
        <GROSS_EXT_AMT>18.00</GROSS_EXT_AMT>
        <LINE_DISC_AMT>-13.20</LINE_DISC_AMT>
        <INV_DISC_AMT>0.00</INV_DISC_AMT>
        <ITEM_TAX>0.00</ITEM_TAX>
        <EXTENDED_AMT>4.80</EXTENDED_AMT>
      </DETAIL>
      <DETAIL>
        <ITEM>0078</ITEM>
        <ITEM_DESCR>FS Additional Features - Machi</ITEM_DESCR>
        <UNIT_OF_MEASURE>EA</UNIT_OF_MEASURE>
        <LIST_PRICE>0.02000</LIST_PRICE>
        <QTY>15</QTY>
        <UNIT_PRICE>0.01667</UNIT_PRICE>
        <LINE_DISC_UNIT>-0.00333</LINE_DISC_UNIT>
        <INV_DISC_UNIT>0.00000</INV_DISC_UNIT>
        <GROSS_EXT_AMT>0.30</GROSS_EXT_AMT>
        <LINE_DISC_AMT>-0.05</LINE_DISC_AMT>
        <INV_DISC_AMT>0.00</INV_DISC_AMT>
        <ITEM_TAX>0.00</ITEM_TAX>
        <EXTENDED_AMT>0.25</EXTENDED_AMT>
      </DETAIL>
      <DETAIL>
        <ITEM>0078</ITEM>
        <ITEM_DESCR>FS Additional Features - Machi</ITEM_DESCR>
        <UNIT_OF_MEASURE>EA</UNIT_OF_MEASURE>
        <LIST_PRICE>0.02067</LIST_PRICE>
        <QTY>15</QTY>
        <UNIT_PRICE>0.01733</UNIT_PRICE>
        <LINE_DISC_UNIT>-0.00333</LINE_DISC_UNIT>
        <INV_DISC_UNIT>0.00000</INV_DISC_UNIT>
        <GROSS_EXT_AMT>0.31</GROSS_EXT_AMT>
        <LINE_DISC_AMT>-0.05</LINE_DISC_AMT>
        <INV_DISC_AMT>0.00</INV_DISC_AMT>
        <ITEM_TAX>0.00</ITEM_TAX>
        <EXTENDED_AMT>0.26</EXTENDED_AMT>
      </DETAIL>
      <DETAIL>
        <ITEM>0078</ITEM>
        <ITEM_DESCR>FS Additional Features - Machi</ITEM_DESCR>
        <UNIT_OF_MEASURE>EA</UNIT_OF_MEASURE>
        <LIST_PRICE>0.02067</LIST_PRICE>
        <QTY>15</QTY>
        <UNIT_PRICE>0.01733</UNIT_PRICE>
        <LINE_DISC_UNIT>-0.00333</LINE_DISC_UNIT>
        <INV_DISC_UNIT>0.00000</INV_DISC_UNIT>
        <GROSS_EXT_AMT>0.31</GROSS_EXT_AMT>
        <LINE_DISC_AMT>-0.05</LINE_DISC_AMT>
        <INV_DISC_AMT>0.00</INV_DISC_AMT>
        <ITEM_TAX>0.00</ITEM_TAX>
        <EXTENDED_AMT>0.26</EXTENDED_AMT>
      </DETAIL>
      <DETAIL>
        <ITEM>0078</ITEM>
        <ITEM_DESCR>FS Additional Features - Machi</ITEM_DESCR>
        <UNIT_OF_MEASURE>EA</UNIT_OF_MEASURE>
        <LIST_PRICE>0.02000</LIST_PRICE>
        <QTY>15</QTY>
        <UNIT_PRICE>0.01667</UNIT_PRICE>
        <LINE_DISC_UNIT>-0.00333</LINE_DISC_UNIT>
        <INV_DISC_UNIT>0.00000</INV_DISC_UNIT>
        <GROSS_EXT_AMT>0.30</GROSS_EXT_AMT>
        <LINE_DISC_AMT>-0.05</LINE_DISC_AMT>
        <INV_DISC_AMT>0.00</INV_DISC_AMT>
        <ITEM_TAX>0.00</ITEM_TAX>
        <EXTENDED_AMT>0.25</EXTENDED_AMT>
      </DETAIL>
      <DETAIL>
        <ITEM>0078</ITEM>
        <ITEM_DESCR>FS Additional Features - Machi</ITEM_DESCR>
        <UNIT_OF_MEASURE>EA</UNIT_OF_MEASURE>
        <LIST_PRICE>0.02000</LIST_PRICE>
        <QTY>15</QTY>
        <UNIT_PRICE>0.01667</UNIT_PRICE>
        <LINE_DISC_UNIT>-0.00333</LINE_DISC_UNIT>
        <INV_DISC_UNIT>0.00000</INV_DISC_UNIT>
        <GROSS_EXT_AMT>0.30</GROSS_EXT_AMT>
        <LINE_DISC_AMT>-0.05</LINE_DISC_AMT>
        <INV_DISC_AMT>0.00</INV_DISC_AMT>
        <ITEM_TAX>0.00</ITEM_TAX>
        <EXTENDED_AMT>0.25</EXTENDED_AMT>
      </DETAIL>
      <DETAIL>
        <ITEM>0078</ITEM>
        <ITEM_DESCR>FS Additional Features - Machi</ITEM_DESCR>
        <UNIT_OF_MEASURE>EA</UNIT_OF_MEASURE>
        <LIST_PRICE>0.02000</LIST_PRICE>
        <QTY>15</QTY>
        <UNIT_PRICE>0.01667</UNIT_PRICE>
        <LINE_DISC_UNIT>-0.00333</LINE_DISC_UNIT>
        <INV_DISC_UNIT>0.00000</INV_DISC_UNIT>
        <GROSS_EXT_AMT>0.30</GROSS_EXT_AMT>
        <LINE_DISC_AMT>-0.05</LINE_DISC_AMT>
        <INV_DISC_AMT>0.00</INV_DISC_AMT>
        <ITEM_TAX>0.00</ITEM_TAX>
        <EXTENDED_AMT>0.25</EXTENDED_AMT>
      </DETAIL>
      <DETAIL>
        <ITEM>0078</ITEM>
        <ITEM_DESCR>FS Additional Features - Machi</ITEM_DESCR>
        <UNIT_OF_MEASURE>EA</UNIT_OF_MEASURE>
        <LIST_PRICE>0.02067</LIST_PRICE>
        <QTY>15</QTY>
        <UNIT_PRICE>0.01733</UNIT_PRICE>
        <LINE_DISC_UNIT>-0.00333</LINE_DISC_UNIT>
        <INV_DISC_UNIT>0.00000</INV_DISC_UNIT>
        <GROSS_EXT_AMT>0.31</GROSS_EXT_AMT>
        <LINE_DISC_AMT>-0.05</LINE_DISC_AMT>
        <INV_DISC_AMT>0.00</INV_DISC_AMT>
        <ITEM_TAX>0.00</ITEM_TAX>
        <EXTENDED_AMT>0.26</EXTENDED_AMT>
      </DETAIL>
      <DETAIL>
        <ITEM>0078</ITEM>
        <ITEM_DESCR>FS Additional Features - Machi</ITEM_DESCR>
        <UNIT_OF_MEASURE>EA</UNIT_OF_MEASURE>
        <LIST_PRICE>0.02067</LIST_PRICE>
        <QTY>15</QTY>
        <UNIT_PRICE>0.01733</UNIT_PRICE>
        <LINE_DISC_UNIT>-0.00333</LINE_DISC_UNIT>
        <INV_DISC_UNIT>0.00000</INV_DISC_UNIT>
        <GROSS_EXT_AMT>0.31</GROSS_EXT_AMT>
        <LINE_DISC_AMT>-0.05</LINE_DISC_AMT>
        <INV_DISC_AMT>0.00</INV_DISC_AMT>
        <ITEM_TAX>0.00</ITEM_TAX>
        <EXTENDED_AMT>0.26</EXTENDED_AMT>
      </DETAIL>
      <DETAIL>
        <ITEM>4531</ITEM>
        <ITEM_DESCR>FXO Local Delivery Standard</ITEM_DESCR>
        <UNIT_OF_MEASURE>EA</UNIT_OF_MEASURE>
        <LIST_PRICE>19.99000</LIST_PRICE>
        <QTY>1</QTY>
        <UNIT_PRICE>0.00000</UNIT_PRICE>
        <LINE_DISC_UNIT>-19.99000</LINE_DISC_UNIT>
        <INV_DISC_UNIT>0.00000</INV_DISC_UNIT>
        <GROSS_EXT_AMT>19.99</GROSS_EXT_AMT>
        <LINE_DISC_AMT>-19.99</LINE_DISC_AMT>
        <INV_DISC_AMT>0.00</INV_DISC_AMT>
        <ITEM_TAX>0.00</ITEM_TAX>
        <EXTENDED_AMT>0.00</EXTENDED_AMT>
      </DETAIL>
    </INVOICE>
    <INVOICE DETAIL_COUNT="3">
      <INV_AR_ID>005700658036A</INV_AR_ID>
      <SOLDTO_ID>0345961518</SOLDTO_ID>
      <SOLDTO_NAME>COMPANY NAME</SOLDTO_NAME>
      <CARD_NO>0000</CARD_NO>
      <CARD_NAME>COMPANY NAME</CARD_NAME>
      <CARD_PHONE>714/222-5525</CARD_PHONE>
      <SIGNEE_NAME>Kelley Katz</SIGNEE_NAME>
      <SIGNEE_PHONE>9495153387</SIGNEE_PHONE>
      <INV_TRANS_ID>10647557</INV_TRANS_ID>
      <INV_TYPE>IN</INV_TYPE>
      <INV_DATE>01/06/16</INV_DATE>
      <INV_AMOUNT>10.17</INV_AMOUNT>
      <INV_CUR_CD>USD</INV_CUR_CD>
      <INV_TAX_TOTAL>0.76</INV_TAX_TOTAL>
      <INV_DISC_TOTAL>0.00</INV_DISC_TOTAL>
      <LINE_DISC_TOTAL>-43.89</LINE_DISC_TOTAL>
      <STORE>0303</STORE>
      <STORE_NAME>Costa Mesa CA</STORE_NAME>
      <STORE_ADDR>1234 Newport Blvd Ste E101</STORE_ADDR>
      <STORE_CITY>Costa Mesa</STORE_CITY>
      <STORE_STATE>CA</STORE_STATE>
      <STORE_POSTAL>92627</STORE_POSTAL>
      <STORE_CNTRY>USA</STORE_CNTRY>
      <PO_REF>0160011156-5711Katz - MLK</PO_REF>
      <DETAIL>
        <ITEM>0033</ITEM>
        <ITEM_DESCR>FS B&amp;W D/S 8.5x11 D/S Standard</ITEM_DESCR>
        <UNIT_OF_MEASURE>EA</UNIT_OF_MEASURE>
        <LIST_PRICE>0.24000</LIST_PRICE>
        <QTY>135</QTY>
        <UNIT_PRICE>0.06400</UNIT_PRICE>
        <LINE_DISC_UNIT>-0.17600</LINE_DISC_UNIT>
        <INV_DISC_UNIT>0.00000</INV_DISC_UNIT>
        <GROSS_EXT_AMT>32.40</GROSS_EXT_AMT>
        <LINE_DISC_AMT>-23.76</LINE_DISC_AMT>
        <INV_DISC_AMT>0.00</INV_DISC_AMT>
        <ITEM_TAX>0.00</ITEM_TAX>
        <EXTENDED_AMT>8.64</EXTENDED_AMT>
      </DETAIL>
      <DETAIL>
        <ITEM>0078</ITEM>
        <ITEM_DESCR>FS Additional Features - Machi</ITEM_DESCR>
        <UNIT_OF_MEASURE>EA</UNIT_OF_MEASURE>
        <LIST_PRICE>0.02022</LIST_PRICE>
        <QTY>45</QTY>
        <UNIT_PRICE>0.01711</UNIT_PRICE>
        <LINE_DISC_UNIT>-0.00311</LINE_DISC_UNIT>
        <INV_DISC_UNIT>0.00000</INV_DISC_UNIT>
        <GROSS_EXT_AMT>0.91</GROSS_EXT_AMT>
        <LINE_DISC_AMT>-0.14</LINE_DISC_AMT>
        <INV_DISC_AMT>0.00</INV_DISC_AMT>
        <ITEM_TAX>0.00</ITEM_TAX>
        <EXTENDED_AMT>0.77</EXTENDED_AMT>
      </DETAIL>
      <DETAIL>
        <ITEM>4531</ITEM>
        <ITEM_DESCR>FXO Local Delivery Standard</ITEM_DESCR>
        <UNIT_OF_MEASURE>EA</UNIT_OF_MEASURE>
        <LIST_PRICE>19.99000</LIST_PRICE>
        <QTY>1</QTY>
        <UNIT_PRICE>0.00000</UNIT_PRICE>
        <LINE_DISC_UNIT>-19.99000</LINE_DISC_UNIT>
        <INV_DISC_UNIT>0.00000</INV_DISC_UNIT>
        <GROSS_EXT_AMT>19.99</GROSS_EXT_AMT>
        <LINE_DISC_AMT>-19.99</LINE_DISC_AMT>
        <INV_DISC_AMT>0.00</INV_DISC_AMT>
        <ITEM_TAX>0.00</ITEM_TAX>
        <EXTENDED_AMT>0.00</EXTENDED_AMT>
      </DETAIL>
    </INVOICE>
  </CUSTOMER>
</EDI_DOCUMENT>
```

Comment: Please provide an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). This way the question is unclear.

Comment: It's unclear what *separate* means in your context: Each invoice into a separate file, etc.? In which way is it related to [tag:xsl-fo]? Your title is misleading; it suggest you want to create an Xsl file from an Xml while your question states you want to process an Xml file using Xsl.

Comment: Do you really mean _from_ this XML file or do you rather mean _for_ this XML file?

Comment: @Paul "*now so that I can display in specific format to the user, I need to create xsl file. My question is how can I create xsl file from this xml file?*" You don't create an XSL file **from** an XML file; you **write** the XSL file as a program to translate the source XML to the target schema. And we can't help you with that without seeing what the "*specific format*" you need as the result looks like.

Comment: The picture is meaningless here. We need to see the original XML and the expected output (also as XML code). And you should have at least a basic understanding of the XSLT language before posting here with a *specific* problem you have run into while trying to do this yourself.

Answer (score 1):

Extracting all `INVOICE` elements to a new XML can be achieved by the following XSLT. The result is wrapped in the `<Invoices>` element.

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" />

  <xsl:template match="/">
    <Invoices>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="//INVOICE"/>    <!-- selects all INVOICE elements in the whole XML -->
    </Invoices>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="INVOICE">
    <xsl:copy-of select="." />                     <!-- copies this INVOICE element to the output -->
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**Output:**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<Invoices>
    <INVOICE DETAIL_COUNT="21">
        <INV_AR_ID>005700658035A</INV_AR_ID>
        <SOLDTO_ID>0345961518</SOLDTO_ID>
        <SOLDTO_NAME>COMPANY NAME</SOLDTO_NAME>
        <CARD_NO>0000</CARD_NO>
        <CARD_NAME>COMPANY NAME</CARD_NAME>
        <CARD_PHONE>714/222-5525</CARD_PHONE>
        <SIGNEE_NAME>elizabeth moore</SIGNEE_NAME>
        <SIGNEE_PHONE>9495016213</SIGNEE_PHONE>
        <INV_TRANS_ID>10647551</INV_TRANS_ID>
        <INV_TYPE>IN</INV_TYPE>
        <INV_DATE>01/06/16</INV_DATE>
        <INV_AMOUNT>49.90</INV_AMOUNT>
        <INV_CUR_CD>USD</INV_CUR_CD>
        <INV_TAX_TOTAL>3.70</INV_TAX_TOTAL>
        <INV_DISC_TOTAL>0.00</INV_DISC_TOTAL>
        <LINE_DISC_TOTAL>-141.83</LINE_DISC_TOTAL>
        <STORE>0303</STORE>
        <STORE_NAME>Costa Mesa CA</STORE_NAME>
        <STORE_ADDR>1234 Newport Blvd Ste E101</STORE_ADDR>
        <STORE_CITY>Costa Mesa</STORE_CITY>
        <STORE_STATE>CA</STORE_STATE>
        <STORE_POSTAL>92627</STORE_POSTAL>
        <STORE_CNTRY>USA</STORE_CNTRY>
        <PO_REF>0162011156-5711MV US DBQs</PO_REF>
        <DETAIL>
            <ITEM>0001</ITEM>
            <ITEM_DESCR>FS B&amp;W S/S White Standard</ITEM_DESCR>
            <UNIT_OF_MEASURE>EA</UNIT_OF_MEASURE>
            <LIST_PRICE>0.12000</LIST_PRICE>
            <QTY>15</QTY>
            <UNIT_PRICE>0.03200</UNIT_PRICE>
            <LINE_DISC_UNIT>-0.08800</LINE_DISC_UNIT>
            <INV_DISC_UNIT>0.00000</INV_DISC_UNIT>
            <GROSS_EXT_AMT>1.80</GROSS_EXT_AMT>
            <LINE_DISC_AMT>-1.32</LINE_DISC_AMT>
            <INV_DISC_AMT>0.00</INV_DISC_AMT>
            <ITEM_TAX>0.00</ITEM_TAX>
            <EXTENDED_AMT>0.48</EXTENDED_AMT>
        </DETAIL>
        <DETAIL>
            <ITEM>0001</ITEM>
            <ITEM_DESCR>FS B&amp;W S/S White Standard</ITEM_DESCR>
            <UNIT_OF_MEASURE>EA</UNIT_OF_MEASURE>
            <LIST_PRICE>0.12000</LIST_PRICE>
            <QTY>15</QTY>
            <UNIT_PRICE>0.03200</UNIT_PRICE>
            <LINE_DISC_UNIT>-0.08800</LINE_DISC_UNIT>
            <INV_DISC_UNIT>0.00000</INV_DISC_UNIT>
            <GROSS_EXT_AMT>1.80</GROSS_EXT_AMT>
            <LINE_DISC_AMT>-1.32</LINE_DISC_AMT>
            <INV_DISC_AMT>0.00</INV_DISC_AMT>
            <ITEM_TAX>0.00</ITEM_TAX>
            <EXTENDED_AMT>0.48</EXTENDED_AMT>
        </DETAIL>
        <DETAIL>
            <ITEM>0001</ITEM>
            <ITEM_DESCR>FS B&amp;W S/S White Standard</ITEM_DESCR>
            <UNIT_OF_MEASURE>EA</UNIT_OF_MEASURE>
            <LIST_PRICE>0.12000</LIST_PRICE>
            <QTY>15</QTY>
            <UNIT_PRICE>0.03200</UNIT_PRICE>
            <LINE_DISC_UNIT>-0.08800</LINE_DISC_UNIT>
            <INV_DISC_UNIT>0.00000</INV_DISC_UNIT>
            <GROSS_EXT_AMT>1.80</GROSS_EXT_AMT>
            <LINE_DISC_AMT>-1.32</LINE_DISC_AMT>
            <INV_DISC_AMT>0.00</INV_DISC_AMT>
            <ITEM_TAX>0.00</ITEM_TAX>
            <EXTENDED_AMT>0.48</EXTENDED_AMT>
        </DETAIL>
        <DETAIL>
            <ITEM>0001</ITEM>
            <ITEM_DESCR>FS B&amp;W S/S White Standard</ITEM_DESCR>
            <UNIT_OF_MEASURE>EA</UNIT_OF_MEASURE>
            <LIST_PRICE>0.12000</LIST_PRICE>
            <QTY>15</QTY>
            <UNIT_PRICE>0.03200</UNIT_PRICE>
            <LINE_DISC_UNIT>-0.08800</LINE_DISC_UNIT>
            <INV_DISC_UNIT>0.00000</INV_DISC_UNIT>
            <GROSS_EXT_AMT>1.80</GROSS_EXT_AMT>
            <LINE_DISC_AMT>-1.32</LINE_DISC_AMT>
            <INV_DISC_AMT>0.00</INV_DISC_AMT>
            <ITEM_TAX>0.00</ITEM_TAX>
            <EXTENDED_AMT>0.48</EXTENDED_AMT>
        </DETAIL>
        <DETAIL>
            <ITEM>0033</ITEM>
            <ITEM_DESCR>FS B&amp;W D/S 8.5x11 D/S Standard</ITEM_DESCR>
            <UNIT_OF_MEASURE>EA</UNIT_OF_MEASURE>
            <LIST_PRICE>0.24000</LIST_PRICE>
            <QTY>90</QTY>
            <UNIT_PRICE>0.06400</UNIT_PRICE>
            <LINE_DISC_UNIT>-0.17600</LINE_DISC_UNIT>
            <INV_DISC_UNIT>0.00000</INV_DISC_UNIT>
            <GROSS_EXT_AMT>21.60</GROSS_EXT_AMT>
            <LINE_DISC_AMT>-15.84</LINE_DISC_AMT>
            <INV_DISC_AMT>0.00</INV_DISC_AMT>
            <ITEM_TAX>0.00</ITEM_TAX>
            <EXTENDED_AMT>5.76</EXTENDED_AMT>
        </DETAIL>
        <DETAIL>
            <ITEM>0033</ITEM>
            <ITEM_DESCR>FS B&amp;W D/S 8.5x11 D/S Standard</ITEM_DESCR>
            <UNIT_OF_MEASURE>EA</UNIT_OF_MEASURE>
            <LIST_PRICE>0.24000</LIST_PRICE>
            <QTY>90</QTY>
            <UNIT_PRICE>0.06400</UNIT_PRICE>
            <LINE_DISC_UNIT>-0.17600</LINE_DISC_UNIT>
            <INV_DISC_UNIT>0.00000</INV_DISC_UNIT>
            <GROSS_EXT_AMT>21.60</GROSS_EXT_AMT>
            <LINE_DISC_AMT>-15.84</LINE_DISC_AMT>
            <INV_DISC_AMT>0.00</INV_DISC_AMT>
            <ITEM_TAX>0.00</ITEM_TAX>
            <EXTENDED_AMT>5.76</EXTENDED_AMT>
        </DETAIL>
        <DETAIL>
            <ITEM>0033</ITEM>
            <ITEM_DESCR>FS B&amp;W D/S 8.5x11 D/S Standard</ITEM_DESCR>
            <UNIT_OF_MEASURE>EA</UNIT_OF_MEASURE>
            <LIST_PRICE>0.24000</LIST_PRICE>
            <QTY>90</QTY>
            <UNIT_PRICE>0.06400</UNIT_PRICE>
            <LINE_DISC_UNIT>-0.17600</LINE_DISC_UNIT>
            <INV_DISC_UNIT>0.00000</INV_DISC_UNIT>
            <GROSS_EXT_AMT>21.60</GROSS_EXT_AMT>
            <LINE_DISC_AMT>-15.84</LINE_DISC_AMT>
            <INV_DISC_AMT>0.00</INV_DISC_AMT>
            <ITEM_TAX>0.00</ITEM_TAX>
            <EXTENDED_AMT>5.76</EXTENDED_AMT>
        </DETAIL>
        <DETAIL>
            <ITEM>0033</ITEM>
            <ITEM_DESCR>FS B&amp;W D/S 8.5x11 D/S Standard</ITEM_DESCR>
            <UNIT_OF_MEASURE>EA</UNIT_OF_MEASURE>
            <LIST_PRICE>0.24000</LIST_PRICE>
            <QTY>75</QTY>
            <UNIT_PRICE>0.06400</UNIT_PRICE>
            <LINE_DISC_UNIT>-0.17600</LINE_DISC_UNIT>
            <INV_DISC_UNIT>0.00000</INV_DISC_UNIT>
            <GROSS_EXT_AMT>18.00</GROSS_EXT_AMT>
            <LINE_DISC_AMT>-13.20</LINE_DISC_AMT>
            <INV_DISC_AMT>0.00</INV_DISC_AMT>
            <ITEM_TAX>0.00</ITEM_TAX>
            <EXTENDED_AMT>4.80</EXTENDED_AMT>
        </DETAIL>
        <DETAIL>
            <ITEM>0033</ITEM>
            <ITEM_DESCR>FS B&amp;W D/S 8.5x11 D/S Standard</ITEM_DESCR>
            <UNIT_OF_MEASURE>EA</UNIT_OF_MEASURE>
            <LIST_PRICE>0.24000</LIST_PRICE>
            <QTY>75</QTY>
            <UNIT_PRICE>0.06400</UNIT_PRICE>
            <LINE_DISC_UNIT>-0.17600</LINE_DISC_UNIT>
            <INV_DISC_UNIT>0.00000</INV_DISC_UNIT>
            <GROSS_EXT_AMT>18.00</GROSS_EXT_AMT>
            <LINE_DISC_AMT>-13.20</LINE_DISC_AMT>
            <INV_DISC_AMT>0.00</INV_DISC_AMT>
            <ITEM_TAX>0.00</ITEM_TAX>
            <EXTENDED_AMT>4.80</EXTENDED_AMT>
        </DETAIL>
        <DETAIL>
            <ITEM>0033</ITEM>
            <ITEM_DESCR>FS B&amp;W D/S 8.5x11 D/S Standard</ITEM_DESCR>
            <UNIT_OF_MEASURE>EA</UNIT_OF_MEASURE>
            <LIST_PRICE>0.24000</LIST_PRICE>
            <QTY>90</QTY>
            <UNIT_PRICE>0.06400</UNIT_PRICE>
            <LINE_DISC_UNIT>-0.17600</LINE_DISC_UNIT>
            <INV_DISC_UNIT>0.00000</INV_DISC_UNIT>
            <GROSS_EXT_AMT>21.60</GROSS_EXT_AMT>
            <LINE_DISC_AMT>-15.84</LINE_DISC_AMT>
            <INV_DISC_AMT>0.00</INV_DISC_AMT>
            <ITEM_TAX>0.00</ITEM_TAX>
            <EXTENDED_AMT>5.76</EXTENDED_AMT>
        </DETAIL>
        <DETAIL>
            <ITEM>0033</ITEM>
            <ITEM_DESCR>FS B&amp;W D/S 8.5x11 D/S Standard</ITEM_DESCR>
            <UNIT_OF_MEASURE>EA</UNIT_OF_MEASURE>
            <LIST_PRICE>0.24000</LIST_PRICE>
            <QTY>75</QTY>
            <UNIT_PRICE>0.06400</UNIT_PRICE>
            <LINE_DISC_UNIT>-0.17600</LINE_DISC_UNIT>
            <INV_DISC_UNIT>0.00000</INV_DISC_UNIT>
            <GROSS_EXT_AMT>18.00</GROSS_EXT_AMT>
            <LINE_DISC_AMT>-13.20</LINE_DISC_AMT>
            <INV_DISC_AMT>0.00</INV_DISC_AMT>
            <ITEM_TAX>0.00</ITEM_TAX>
            <EXTENDED_AMT>4.80</EXTENDED_AMT>
        </DETAIL>
        <DETAIL>
            <ITEM>0033</ITEM>
            <ITEM_DESCR>FS B&amp;W D/S 8.5x11 D/S Standard</ITEM_DESCR>
            <UNIT_OF_MEASURE>EA</UNIT_OF_MEASURE>
            <LIST_PRICE>0.24000</LIST_PRICE>
            <QTY>75</QTY>
            <UNIT_PRICE>0.06400</UNIT_PRICE>
            <LINE_DISC_UNIT>-0.17600</LINE_DISC_UNIT>
            <INV_DISC_UNIT>0.00000</INV_DISC_UNIT>
            <GROSS_EXT_AMT>18.00</GROSS_EXT_AMT>
            <LINE_DISC_AMT>-13.20</LINE_DISC_AMT>
            <INV_DISC_AMT>0.00</INV_DISC_AMT>
            <ITEM_TAX>0.00</ITEM_TAX>
            <EXTENDED_AMT>4.80</EXTENDED_AMT>
        </DETAIL>
        <DETAIL>
            <ITEM>0078</ITEM>
            <ITEM_DESCR>FS Additional Features - Machi</ITEM_DESCR>
            <UNIT_OF_MEASURE>EA</UNIT_OF_MEASURE>
            <LIST_PRICE>0.02000</LIST_PRICE>
            <QTY>15</QTY>
            <UNIT_PRICE>0.01667</UNIT_PRICE>
            <LINE_DISC_UNIT>-0.00333</LINE_DISC_UNIT>
            <INV_DISC_UNIT>0.00000</INV_DISC_UNIT>
            <GROSS_EXT_AMT>0.30</GROSS_EXT_AMT>
            <LINE_DISC_AMT>-0.05</LINE_DISC_AMT>
            <INV_DISC_AMT>0.00</INV_DISC_AMT>
            <ITEM_TAX>0.00</ITEM_TAX>
            <EXTENDED_AMT>0.25</EXTENDED_AMT>
        </DETAIL>
        <DETAIL>
            <ITEM>0078</ITEM>
            <ITEM_DESCR>FS Additional Features - Machi</ITEM_DESCR>
            <UNIT_OF_MEASURE>EA</UNIT_OF_MEASURE>
            <LIST_PRICE>0.02067</LIST_PRICE>
            <QTY>15</QTY>
            <UNIT_PRICE>0.01733</UNIT_PRICE>
            <LINE_DISC_UNIT>-0.00333</LINE_DISC_UNIT>
            <INV_DISC_UNIT>0.00000</INV_DISC_UNIT>
            <GROSS_EXT_AMT>0.31</GROSS_EXT_AMT>
            <LINE_DISC_AMT>-0.05</LINE_DISC_AMT>
            <INV_DISC_AMT>0.00</INV_DISC_AMT>
            <ITEM_TAX>0.00</ITEM_TAX>
            <EXTENDED_AMT>0.26</EXTENDED_AMT>
        </DETAIL>
        <DETAIL>
            <ITEM>0078</ITEM>
            <ITEM_DESCR>FS Additional Features - Machi</ITEM_DESCR>
            <UNIT_OF_MEASURE>EA</UNIT_OF_MEASURE>
            <LIST_PRICE>0.02067</LIST_PRICE>
            <QTY>15</QTY>
            <UNIT_PRICE>0.01733</UNIT_PRICE>
            <LINE_DISC_UNIT>-0.00333</LINE_DISC_UNIT>
            <INV_DISC_UNIT>0.00000</INV_DISC_UNIT>
            <GROSS_EXT_AMT>0.31</GROSS_EXT_AMT>
            <LINE_DISC_AMT>-0.05</LINE_DISC_AMT>
            <INV_DISC_AMT>0.00</INV_DISC_AMT>
            <ITEM_TAX>0.00</ITEM_TAX>
            <EXTENDED_AMT>0.26</EXTENDED_AMT>
        </DETAIL>
        <DETAIL>
            <ITEM>0078</ITEM>
            <ITEM_DESCR>FS Additional Features - Machi</ITEM_DESCR>
            <UNIT_OF_MEASURE>EA</UNIT_OF_MEASURE>
            <LIST_PRICE>0.02000</LIST_PRICE>
            <QTY>15</QTY>
            <UNIT_PRICE>0.01667</UNIT_PRICE>
            <LINE_DISC_UNIT>-0.00333</LINE_DISC_UNIT>
            <INV_DISC_UNIT>0.00000</INV_DISC_UNIT>
            <GROSS_EXT_AMT>0.30</GROSS_EXT_AMT>
            <LINE_DISC_AMT>-0.05</LINE_DISC_AMT>
            <INV_DISC_AMT>0.00</INV_DISC_AMT>
            <ITEM_TAX>0.00</ITEM_TAX>
            <EXTENDED_AMT>0.25</EXTENDED_AMT>
        </DETAIL>
        <DETAIL>
            <ITEM>0078</ITEM>
            <ITEM_DESCR>FS Additional Features - Machi</ITEM_DESCR>
            <UNIT_OF_MEASURE>EA</UNIT_OF_MEASURE>
            <LIST_PRICE>0.02000</LIST_PRICE>
            <QTY>15</QTY>
            <UNIT_PRICE>0.01667</UNIT_PRICE>
            <LINE_DISC_UNIT>-0.00333</LINE_DISC_UNIT>
            <INV_DISC_UNIT>0.00000</INV_DISC_UNIT>
            <GROSS_EXT_AMT>0.30</GROSS_EXT_AMT>
            <LINE_DISC_AMT>-0.05</LINE_DISC_AMT>
            <INV_DISC_AMT>0.00</INV_DISC_AMT>
            <ITEM_TAX>0.00</ITEM_TAX>
            <EXTENDED_AMT>0.25</EXTENDED_AMT>
        </DETAIL>
        <DETAIL>
            <ITEM>0078</ITEM>
            <ITEM_DESCR>FS Additional Features - Machi</ITEM_DESCR>
            <UNIT_OF_MEASURE>EA</UNIT_OF_MEASURE>
            <LIST_PRICE>0.02000</LIST_PRICE>
            <QTY>15</QTY>
            <UNIT_PRICE>0.01667</UNIT_PRICE>
            <LINE_DISC_UNIT>-0.00333</LINE_DISC_UNIT>
            <INV_DISC_UNIT>0.00000</INV_DISC_UNIT>
            <GROSS_EXT_AMT>0.30</GROSS_EXT_AMT>
            <LINE_DISC_AMT>-0.05</LINE_DISC_AMT>
            <INV_DISC_AMT>0.00</INV_DISC_AMT>
            <ITEM_TAX>0.00</ITEM_TAX>
            <EXTENDED_AMT>0.25</EXTENDED_AMT>
        </DETAIL>
        <DETAIL>
            <ITEM>0078</ITEM>
            <ITEM_DESCR>FS Additional Features - Machi</ITEM_DESCR>
            <UNIT_OF_MEASURE>EA</UNIT_OF_MEASURE>
            <LIST_PRICE>0.02067</LIST_PRICE>
            <QTY>15</QTY>
            <UNIT_PRICE>0.01733</UNIT_PRICE>
            <LINE_DISC_UNIT>-0.00333</LINE_DISC_UNIT>
            <INV_DISC_UNIT>0.00000</INV_DISC_UNIT>
            <GROSS_EXT_AMT>0.31</GROSS_EXT_AMT>
            <LINE_DISC_AMT>-0.05</LINE_DISC_AMT>
            <INV_DISC_AMT>0.00</INV_DISC_AMT>
            <ITEM_TAX>0.00</ITEM_TAX>
            <EXTENDED_AMT>0.26</EXTENDED_AMT>
        </DETAIL>
        <DETAIL>
            <ITEM>0078</ITEM>
            <ITEM_DESCR>FS Additional Features - Machi</ITEM_DESCR>
            <UNIT_OF_MEASURE>EA</UNIT_OF_MEASURE>
            <LIST_PRICE>0.02067</LIST_PRICE>
            <QTY>15</QTY>
            <UNIT_PRICE>0.01733</UNIT_PRICE>
            <LINE_DISC_UNIT>-0.00333</LINE_DISC_UNIT>
            <INV_DISC_UNIT>0.00000</INV_DISC_UNIT>
            <GROSS_EXT_AMT>0.31</GROSS_EXT_AMT>
            <LINE_DISC_AMT>-0.05</LINE_DISC_AMT>
            <INV_DISC_AMT>0.00</INV_DISC_AMT>
            <ITEM_TAX>0.00</ITEM_TAX>
            <EXTENDED_AMT>0.26</EXTENDED_AMT>
        </DETAIL>
        <DETAIL>
            <ITEM>4531</ITEM>
            <ITEM_DESCR>FXO Local Delivery Standard</ITEM_DESCR>
            <UNIT_OF_MEASURE>EA</UNIT_OF_MEASURE>
            <LIST_PRICE>19.99000</LIST_PRICE>
            <QTY>1</QTY>
            <UNIT_PRICE>0.00000</UNIT_PRICE>
            <LINE_DISC_UNIT>-19.99000</LINE_DISC_UNIT>
            <INV_DISC_UNIT>0.00000</INV_DISC_UNIT>
            <GROSS_EXT_AMT>19.99</GROSS_EXT_AMT>
            <LINE_DISC_AMT>-19.99</LINE_DISC_AMT>
            <INV_DISC_AMT>0.00</INV_DISC_AMT>
            <ITEM_TAX>0.00</ITEM_TAX>
            <EXTENDED_AMT>0.00</EXTENDED_AMT>
        </DETAIL>
    </INVOICE>
    <INVOICE DETAIL_COUNT="3">
        <INV_AR_ID>005700658036A</INV_AR_ID>
        <SOLDTO_ID>0345961518</SOLDTO_ID>
        <SOLDTO_NAME>COMPANY NAME</SOLDTO_NAME>
        <CARD_NO>0000</CARD_NO>
        <CARD_NAME>COMPANY NAME</CARD_NAME>
        <CARD_PHONE>714/222-5525</CARD_PHONE>
        <SIGNEE_NAME>Kelley Katz</SIGNEE_NAME>
        <SIGNEE_PHONE>9495153387</SIGNEE_PHONE>
        <INV_TRANS_ID>10647557</INV_TRANS_ID>
        <INV_TYPE>IN</INV_TYPE>
        <INV_DATE>01/06/16</INV_DATE>
        <INV_AMOUNT>10.17</INV_AMOUNT>
        <INV_CUR_CD>USD</INV_CUR_CD>
        <INV_TAX_TOTAL>0.76</INV_TAX_TOTAL>
        <INV_DISC_TOTAL>0.00</INV_DISC_TOTAL>
        <LINE_DISC_TOTAL>-43.89</LINE_DISC_TOTAL>
        <STORE>0303</STORE>
        <STORE_NAME>Costa Mesa CA</STORE_NAME>
        <STORE_ADDR>1234 Newport Blvd Ste E101</STORE_ADDR>
        <STORE_CITY>Costa Mesa</STORE_CITY>
        <STORE_STATE>CA</STORE_STATE>
        <STORE_POSTAL>92627</STORE_POSTAL>
        <STORE_CNTRY>USA</STORE_CNTRY>
        <PO_REF>0160011156-5711Katz - MLK</PO_REF>
        <DETAIL>
            <ITEM>0033</ITEM>
            <ITEM_DESCR>FS B&amp;W D/S 8.5x11 D/S Standard</ITEM_DESCR>
            <UNIT_OF_MEASURE>EA</UNIT_OF_MEASURE>
            <LIST_PRICE>0.24000</LIST_PRICE>
            <QTY>135</QTY>
            <UNIT_PRICE>0.06400</UNIT_PRICE>
            <LINE_DISC_UNIT>-0.17600</LINE_DISC_UNIT>
            <INV_DISC_UNIT>0.00000</INV_DISC_UNIT>
            <GROSS_EXT_AMT>32.40</GROSS_EXT_AMT>
            <LINE_DISC_AMT>-23.76</LINE_DISC_AMT>
            <INV_DISC_AMT>0.00</INV_DISC_AMT>
            <ITEM_TAX>0.00</ITEM_TAX>
            <EXTENDED_AMT>8.64</EXTENDED_AMT>
        </DETAIL>
        <DETAIL>
            <ITEM>0078</ITEM>
            <ITEM_DESCR>FS Additional Features - Machi</ITEM_DESCR>
            <UNIT_OF_MEASURE>EA</UNIT_OF_MEASURE>
            <LIST_PRICE>0.02022</LIST_PRICE>
            <QTY>45</QTY>
            <UNIT_PRICE>0.01711</UNIT_PRICE>
            <LINE_DISC_UNIT>-0.00311</LINE_DISC_UNIT>
            <INV_DISC_UNIT>0.00000</INV_DISC_UNIT>
            <GROSS_EXT_AMT>0.91</GROSS_EXT_AMT>
            <LINE_DISC_AMT>-0.14</LINE_DISC_AMT>
            <INV_DISC_AMT>0.00</INV_DISC_AMT>
            <ITEM_TAX>0.00</ITEM_TAX>
            <EXTENDED_AMT>0.77</EXTENDED_AMT>
        </DETAIL>
        <DETAIL>
            <ITEM>4531</ITEM>
            <ITEM_DESCR>FXO Local Delivery Standard</ITEM_DESCR>
            <UNIT_OF_MEASURE>EA</UNIT_OF_MEASURE>
            <LIST_PRICE>19.99000</LIST_PRICE>
            <QTY>1</QTY>
            <UNIT_PRICE>0.00000</UNIT_PRICE>
            <LINE_DISC_UNIT>-19.99000</LINE_DISC_UNIT>
            <INV_DISC_UNIT>0.00000</INV_DISC_UNIT>
            <GROSS_EXT_AMT>19.99</GROSS_EXT_AMT>
            <LINE_DISC_AMT>-19.99</LINE_DISC_AMT>
            <INV_DISC_AMT>0.00</INV_DISC_AMT>
            <ITEM_TAX>0.00</ITEM_TAX>
            <EXTENDED_AMT>0.00</EXTENDED_AMT>
        </DETAIL>
    </INVOICE>
</Invoices>
```

Comment: Thanks for the idea, it helps a lot.